# Ubuntu Installation - Loading Time

Tags: ubuntu, installation

I am Installing Ubuntu side by side to my windows. I have selected `/dev/sda5` to mount the `/` on, and the `/dev/sda4` to mount the `/boot` on. Do you think this will present any problems? I have pressed the `Install Now` and it has been loading for 6 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which partition windows sits on?

If you install ubuntu on NTFS partition - I think it will be slow.

If you want to install windows and ubuntu on the same disk - please install them on the different partitions - and format windows as ntfs and ubuntu as ext4

Answer (score 0):

IMO, no problem will happen provided it doesn't conflict with your windows partition.

As you already started I don't think you have any options available, but if by any chance you get into booting problems, you can use `ubuntu-boot-disk-repair` or windows boot manager (many software available)